# constructing pandas dataframe from csv that has columns of dictionaries

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dictionary

I have a csv that contains multiple columns filled with a single dict. There are thousands of rows. I want to pull these dicts out and make columns out of their keys and fill the cells in with their values, filling in NaN where a value is missing. So that:

```
   id                            attributes
0   255RSSSTCHL-QLTDGLZD-BLK     {"color": "Black", "hardware": "Goldtone"}
1   C3ACCRDNFLP-QLTDS-S-BLK      {"size": "Small", "color": "Black"}
```

Becomes:

```
   id                            size   color   hardware  
0   255RSSSTCHL-QLTDGLZD-BLK     NaN    Black   Goldtone
1   C3ACCRDNFLP-QLTDS-S-BLK      Small  Black   NaN
```

There are several columns like 'id' that I would like to keep untouched in the resulting DataFrame and there are several columns like 'attributes' that are filled with dicts that I want to blow out into columns. I truncated them to the example above for illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Source DF:**

```
In [172]: df
Out[172]:
                         id                               attributes                       attr2
0  255RSSSTCHL-QLTDGLZD-BLK  {"color":"Black","hardware":"Goldtone"}  {"aaa":"aaa", "bbb":"bbb"}
1   C3ACCRDNFLP-QLTDS-S-BLK         {"size":"Small","color":"Black"}               {"ccc":"ccc"}
```

**Solution 1:**

```
import ast

attr_cols = ['attributes','attr2']

def f(df, attr_col):
    return df.join(df.pop(attr_col) \
             .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(ast.literal_eval(x))))


for col in attr_cols:
    df = f(df, col)
```

**Solution 2:** thanks to [@DYZ for the hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769733/constructing-pandas-dataframe-from-csv-that-has-columns-of-dictionaries/43769792?noredirect=1#comment74581521_43769792):

```
import json

attr_cols = ['attributes','attr2']

def f(df, attr_col):
    return df.join(df.pop(attr_col) \
             .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x))))

for col in attr_cols:
    df = f(df, col)
```

**Result:**

```
In [175]: df
Out[175]:
                         id  color  hardware   size  aaa  bbb  ccc
0  255RSSSTCHL-QLTDGLZD-BLK  Black  Goldtone    NaN  aaa  bbb  NaN
1   C3ACCRDNFLP-QLTDS-S-BLK  Black       NaN  Small  NaN  NaN  ccc
```

**Timing:** for 20.000 rows DF:

```
In [198]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [199]: df.shape
Out[199]: (20000, 3)

In [201]: %paste
def f_ast(df, attr_col):
    return df.join(df.pop(attr_col) \
             .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(ast.literal_eval(x))))

def f_json(df, attr_col):
    return df.join(df.pop(attr_col) \
             .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x))))
## -- End pasted text --

In [202]: %%timeit
     ...: for col in attr_cols:
     ...:     f_ast(df.copy(), col)
     ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 33.1 s per loop

In [203]:

In [203]: %%timeit
     ...: for col in attr_cols:
     ...:     f_json(df.copy(), col)
     ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 30 s per loop

In [204]: df.shape
Out[204]: (20000, 3)
```

Comment: If the dictionaries are also valid JSON objects, then `json.loads` is about 5% faster than `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @DYZ, i've added a timing - for that DF it was 10% faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could embed the string parsing in the `pd.read_csv` call using the `converters` option

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge as dmerge
from json import loads

txt = """id|attributes|attr2
255RSSSTCHL-QLTDGLZD-BLK|{"color":"Black","hardware":"Goldtone"}|{"aaa":"aaa", "bbb":"bbb"}
C3ACCRDNFLP-QLTDS-S-BLK|{"size":"Small","color":"Black"}|{"ccc":"ccc"}"""

converters = dict(attributes=loads, attr2=loads)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='|', index_col='id', converters=converters)
df
```

[image]

Then we can `merge` the dictionaries across each row and convert to a `pd.DataFrame`.  I'll use `cytoolz.dicttoolz.merge` imported as `dmerge` above.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.apply(dmerge, 1).values.tolist(), df.index).reset_index()

                         id  aaa  bbb  ccc  color  hardware   size
0  255RSSSTCHL-QLTDGLZD-BLK  aaa  bbb  NaN  Black  Goldtone    NaN
1   C3ACCRDNFLP-QLTDS-S-BLK  NaN  NaN  ccc  Black       NaN  Small
```